# SVG path element round corner thickness

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to create rectangle with round corner using path element but the problem is that round corner have more stroke width then straight lines. See code below for path element.

```
<svg width="596.8571428571429" height="403.48571428571427">
    <g class="cardBG" opacity="0.8">
        <path 
            d="M104,0
               h388.8571428571429
               a104,104 0 0 1 104,104
               v195.48571428571427
               v104
               h-104
               h-388.8571428571429
               h-104
               v-104
               v-195.48571428571427
               a104,104 0 0 1 104,-104z" fill="none" 
            stroke="#000000" stroke-width="12">
        </path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

jsfidle
https://jsfiddle.net/w9s0e3fu/2/

How can I make sure that stroke width remains consistent for whole path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stroke *is* correctly sized, but its being cut off by the viewport. You could expand your viewport by adding a `viewBox` that is offset to the `left` and `top` by *half* your `stroke-width` (ie. `12/2=6`), and has a `width` and `height` of your path but *including* two halves of your `stroke-width` that are missing (ie. `2*6=12`):

```
viewBox="-6 -6 609 416"
```

```html
<svg width="597" height="404" viewBox="-6 -6 609 416">
    <g class="cardBG" opacity="0.8">
        <path 
            d="M104,0
               h388.8571428571429
               a104,104 0 0 1 104,104
               v195.48571428571427
               v104
               h-104
               h-388.8571428571429
               h-104
               v-104
               v-195.48571428571427
               a104,104 0 0 1 104,-104z" fill="none" 
            stroke="#000000" stroke-width="12">
        </path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Keep in mind that changing your stroke thickness would need to change these values, as strokes get drawn from the center of the line, so if your line hugs the side of the viewport then one half of the stroke will be cut off. Better to create some more space, if allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a svg path pattern which full fill your requirements.


**Description:**

**m100,100:** move to point(100,100)

**h200:** draw a 200px horizontal line from where we are

**a20,20 0 0 1 20,20:** draw an arc with 20px X radius, 20px Y radius, clockwise, to a point with 20px difference in X and Y axis

**v200:** draw a 200px vertical line from where we are

**a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20:** draw an arc with 20px X and Y radius, clockwise, to a point with -20px difference in X and 20px difference in Y axis

**h-200:** draw a -200px horizontal line from where we are

**a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20:** draw an arc with 20px X and Y radius, clockwise, to a point with -20px difference in X and -20px difference in Y axis

**v-200:** draw a -200px vertical line from where we are

**a20,20 0 0 1 20,-20:** draw an arc with 20px X and Y radius, clockwise, to a point with 20px difference in X and -20px difference in Y axis

**z:** close the path

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <path d="M100,100 h200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 v200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 h-200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 v-200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,-20 z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="10"/>
</svg>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <path d="M100,100 h200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 v200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 h-200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 v-200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,-20 z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="10"/>
</svg> 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Except that it is actually a different shape, as only the two top corners are rounded in the OPs question.

Comment: Yes right @somethinghere but that is a common solution and I think we can easily fix that :) Thanks !!

Comment: I think it might be best if you also set out to explain what you have done and why you have done it, so the OP can learn from your answer and not just copy paste it. This person is obviously trying to get down with SVG, so telling him _why_ the stroke cuts off and how to solve it is better than just posting a fixed version.

Comment: See I added the description :)

Comment: Okay thats a good effort :) The issue is, I'm sure the OP already knows this stuff as he used all of the above in his post to illustrate the problem he was trying to solve. The issue is with the _border_ and why it wasn't consistent in width in his example... I presume you just redrew the shape but inside the viewport, yet none of your explanation tries to tell the OP that that's why yours works.

Comment: You already highlighted why this issue coming in his example.. You explain it more better than me :P, So I don't need to copy again lol :)

Comment: Your answer could be just as valid as mine, don't rely on my answer, try to give complete answers that solve the issue and explain what is going in without relying on somebody else's post. I understand where you are coming from but I believe a good answer on Stack Overflow is self-contained and tries to help solving a problem, and those answers get upvotes. Also, your _solution_ is different - mine is to expand the viewBox, yours is to redraw the shape but smaller so it wont fall outside the viewBox. Thats just as valid a solution, but you never mention it...